# How does moment.js determine the locale

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am wondering if anyone has a clear idea of how moment.js determines the locale. Does it get it from the browser or the system? I am using `moment.format(lll)` to show local date formats for different regions. The docs do not appear to be specific about this? There is one section that states locales have to be loaded, but that did not answer my question.

Comment: Moment by default uses english locale without looking at environment settings (e.g. browser locale), if you need you can [Change locale globally](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/changing-locale/) or [Change locales locally](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/instance-locale/).

Answer (score 0):

From the docs: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/changing-locale/

> By default, Moment.js comes with English (United States) locale strings. If you need other locales, you can load them into Moment.js for later use.
>
> To load a locale, pass the key and the string values to moment.locale.

To set/load a locale:

```
moment.locale('fr');  // Set the default/global locale
```